# What does the eigenvalue tell us?

Tags: differential-geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, image-processing, hessian-matrix

Given an grayscale image and a position $(x,y)$ at which i've calculated the Hessian $H(x,y) = \left( \begin{matrix}I_{xx} & I_{xy} \\ I_{xy} & I_{yy} \end{matrix} \right)$, where the $I_{xx/xy/yy}$ are the second order derivatives of the image $I$ in the direction $xx$, $xy$ and $yy$. I know that the eigenvector of $H$ corresponding to the largest eigenvalue indicates the direction of greatest curvature. But what does the eigenvalue itself tell us? The larger it is the larger is the curvature at this point? Or does the value itself not matter?

Comment: The eigenvalues are [principal curvatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_curvature).

Comment: ...if $(x,y)$ is a stationary point. In general they're proportional to the principal curvatures by some function of $|\nabla I(x,y)|$.

Comment: From this wikipedia article: "They measure how the surface bends by different amounts in different directions at that point" This means, that if i have two points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ and i calculate the largest eigenvalues of theire Hessian matrices ($\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$) then i can say if $\lambda_1 > \lambda_2$ then there is more curvature at $(x_1,y_1)$ than at the other point?